# Connect linux to mysql on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, .htaccess

I am trying to connect to a mysql database on a windows server from linux.  I don't have much experience working with Windows at all, especially windows server.  How do I go about making a connection to the mySQL database from Linux?  I was also wondering (and this should maybe be a different thread) if there is a Windows equivalent to the apache .htaccess file that would handle rewrites?

Comment: Yes, different thread. Different site too.

Comment: Remotely connecting to MySQL on a Windows host is no different to connecting to MySQL on any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Where the settings are placed depend on the client you're using, but you must specify the remote (Linux) host machine's address and port number (at least if not default) when connecting your client.

It is possible to run Apache on Windows. If you're trying to run a different web server, you need to to split that to another question.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect to your MySQL as if it was on a linux machine (Just specify the hostname/IP address and port)
Make sure that there is no firewall rule preventing this connection